# Writing a function to modify strings within a list

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a function that takes one argument: a list of strings.

Each string is the short form for a day, for example: 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', etc.

The function should return a new list with each day converted to it's full name: 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', etc.

For example, when we run:

```
result = format_days(['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'])
print(result)
```

then we expect the output to be:

`['Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday']`
​

If there is a short day name that is not recognised, it should ignore this day and filter it from the formatted list.

For example, if we invoked the function like:

```
result = format_days(['Sat', 'Fun', 'Tue', 'Thu'])
print(result)
```

Then the output would be:

```
['Saturday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday']
```

The function only has to convert all days of the week into their full names:
Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun to Monday, Tuesday... etc.

I'm not exactly sure what to write in my function, help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: _I’m not exactly sure what the write in my function_ That’s not a specific problem, Stack Overflow is a not substitute for guides and tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilising a dictionary you can set the `keys` to the abbreviated version of the day and the value to the display name.

```
def format_days(data):
    days = {'Mon': 'Monday',
        'Tue': 'Tuesday',
        'Wed': 'Wednesday',
        'Thu': 'Thursday',
        'Fri': 'Friday',
        }
    return [days[v] for v in data if v in days]

format_days(['Mon', 'Fri', 'Thu'])
```

Output:

```
['Monday', 'Friday', 'Thursday']
```